# Local copy of Rails in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently upgraded a rails project I am working on from 2.0.5 to 2.3.2. I noticed that there was a local copy of the 2.0.5 rails files in vendor/rails and I was wondering should I put a local copy the 2.3.2 rails files in there too or just leave them out? What is considered a better practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The copy of Rails that sits in `vendor/rails` is actually used in preference to the Rails gems installed system-wide—in other words, though you upgraded your Rails install, your app is actually still running on 2.0.5.

The `vendor/rails` directory exists so you can "freeze" your app to a specific version of Rails, thus making it less vulnerable to changes in the configuration of the machine it's running on.  This is so darned useful that there's an automated way to manage the directory.  To delete the existing version of Rails sitting in `vendor/rails`, go to the root of your Rails project directory and do the following:

```
rake rails:unfreeze
```

To then install the most current Rails gems on your system into `vendor/rails`, do:

```
rake rails:freeze:gems
```

There are a few other things you can do with `vendor/rails`.  Check out `rake -T` for a full list of commands.

P.S. If you ever hear someone talk about their Rails install being "vendored", this is what they mean.

Comment: Yea I noticed that it was using the local copy so I just simply removed the rails dir from vendor. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile things have changed a little.

```
rake rails:freeze
```

and

```
rake rails:unfreeze
```

are deprecated. Instead you should use:

```
 bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

and

```
bundle install --system
```

to switch back.